# how display row content in a modal after onclick remove row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a data table, which I want to use to display all the content in a row on a modal.

when I click the (approve and reject) button for the selected row, after which when "rejected" and  "approved" the whole row is removed. I have included this in my HTML and JavaScript code externally.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
  $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});
// select with checkbox
jQuery('#master').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked', true)) {
    $(".check").prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $(".check").prop('checked', false);
  }
});
//bulk approval 
$('.approve').on('click', function() {
  alert("The requisitions have been approved");
  $('td input:checked').closest('tr').remove();
});
//bulk query 
$('.query').on('click', function() {
  alert("The requisitions have been queried");
  ('.check').prop('checked', false);
});
//bulk rejection
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
  confirm("Reject the requisition");
  $('td input:checked').closest('tr').remove();
});

function remove() {
  document.getElementById("dtBasicExample").deleteRow(1);
}
// reject requisition
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".close").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("dtBasicExample").deleteRow(1);
    $(".modal2").modal("hide");
  });
});
// approve requisition
$(document).ready(function() {
  // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
  $("#dtBasicExample").on('click', '.btn-outline-success', function() {
    // get the current row
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 
    var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text();
    var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text();
    var col4 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text();
    var data = "The requisition with number " +
      col1 + " initiated by " + col2 + " of " + col4 + " " + col3 + " 
    has been approved ";
    document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].innerHTML = data;
    document.getElementById("dtBasicExample").deleteRow(1);
  });
})
// query requisition
$(document).ready(function() {
  // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
  $("#dtBasicExample").on('click', '.btn-outline-warning', function() {
    // get the current row
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st TD 
    value
    var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // get current row 2nd TD
    var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text();
    var col4 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text(); // get current row 3rd TD
    var data = "The requisition with number " + col1 + " initiated by " +
      col2 + " of " + col4 + " " + col3 + " has been queried";
    document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].innerHTML = data;
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.9/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div style="position: absolute; right: 40%; z-index:5">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm approve">Approve</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm query">Query</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">Reject</button>
  </div>
  <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table btn-table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="master" class=""></th>
        <th class="th-sm">Number<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        <th class="th-sm">Location<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        <th class="th-sm">Initiator<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        <th class="th-sm">Currency<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        <th class="th-sm">Amount<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        <th class="th-sm">Approve &nbsp; &nbsp; Query &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Reject</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check">
        </td>
        <td>PO13238</td>
        <td>Ibese</td>
        <td>Yusuf Jimoh</td>
        <td>Naira</td>
        <td>150,000</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal2"><i 
                                                                                                                                        class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check">
        </td>
        <td>PO13238</td>
        <td>Ibese</td>
        <td>Toba Jimoh</td>
        <td>Naira</td>
        <td>150,000</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal2"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check">
        </td>
        <td>PO13238</td>
        <td>Ibese</td>
        <td>Dauda Jimoh</td>
        <td>Naira</td>
        <td>150,000</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal2"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check">
        </td>
        <td>PO13238</td>
        <td>Ibese</td>
        <td>Lateef Jimoh</td>
        <td>Naira</td>
        <td>150,000</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal2"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check">
        </td>
        <td>PO13238</td>
        <td>Ibese</td>
        <td>Jimoh Ishola</td>
        <td>Dollar</td>
        <td>350,000</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal2"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Check</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Initiator</th>
        <th>Currency</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Approve &nbsp; &nbsp; Query &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Reject
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <!-- Modal for query and approve -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="basicExampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal for delete-->
  <div class="modal fade modal2" id="basicExampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Reject Requisition ?</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md close">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDBootstrap Datatables  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/addons/datatables.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current attempt is just a bit broad `$("#dtBasicExample").on('click', '.btn-outline-success', function() {` You can attach a click listener to each row and loop through the `<td>`'s of that clicked row to create your data string that is added to the modal body.

You also should use unique id's so I added a `2` to your second modal's id attribute.

Also you need to loop through each modal body (2 of them in this case) and replace the html with your data.

Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("tbody tr").on('click', function() {
    let data = "";

    // loop through all the tds in the clicked row and prepare their text
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      data += $(this).text() + "<br/>";
    });

    // add the data to all nodes with a class modal-body
    $('.modal-body').each(function() {
      $(this).html(data);
    });

    // show the first modal (for this example only)
    $("#basicExampleModal").modal("show");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div style="position: absolute; right: 40%; z-index:5">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm approve">Approve</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm query">Query</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">Reject</button>
  </div>
  <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table btn-table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="master" class=""></th>
        <th class="th-sm">Number<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        <th class="th-sm">Location<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        <th class="th-sm">Initiator<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        <th class="th-sm">Currency<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        <th class="th-sm">Amount<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        <th class="th-sm">Approve &nbsp; &nbsp; Query &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Reject</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check">
        </td>
        <td>PO13238</td>
        <td>Ibese</td>
        <td>Yusuf Jimoh</td>
        <td>Naira</td>
        <td>150,000</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal2"><i 
                                                                                                                                        class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check">
        </td>
        <td>PO13238</td>
        <td>Ibese</td>
        <td>Toba Jimoh</td>
        <td>Naira</td>
        <td>150,000</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal2"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Check</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Initiator</th>
        <th>Currency</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Approve &nbsp; &nbsp; Query &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Reject
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <!-- Modal for query and approve -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="basicExampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal for delete-->
  <div class="modal fade modal2" id="basicExampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Reject Requisition ?</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md close">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the modal is supposed to show the details after the selected button has been clicked not when the check box is selected thereafter the row is removed.

Comment: yes, it is currently that way because its just an example so you can see it. That is why I put the comment `// show the first modal (for this example only)`